# Different Default Arguments to pocketsphinx_continuous

Tags: pocketsphinx

I'm calling `pocketsphinx_continuous` from the terminal and also through the `system` command in `R`. I use the exact same arguments but I get an error when I run it in R while the one from the terminal runs fine. I've attached the logs below in which I can see some of the unspecified arguments to be different, eg. `dict`, `fdict`, and some of the comments at the end also different, eg. `Allocating 4101 * 32 bytes (128 KiB) for word entries`.

How do I resolve the error? Any reason why the differences arise?

Logs below:

From `R`'s `system` command -

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm  /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new -infile  /SpeechParsing/Record_0039.wav -kws  /SpeechParsing/KeyPhrase.txt -time yes >  /tmp/Rtmpxuznpx/file3ef93d02074d

INFO: pocketsphinx.c(145): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]          [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc            none        none
-agcthresh      2.0     2.000000e+00
-allphone               
-allphone_ci        no      no
-alpha          0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale         20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw         1       1
-backtrace      no      no
-beam           1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath       yes     yes
-bestpathlw     9.5     9.500000e+00
-ceplen         13      13
-cmn            current     current
-cmninit        8.0     40,3,-1
-compallsen     no      no
-debug                  0
-dict                   
-dictcase       no      no
-dither         no      no
-doublebw       no      no
-ds         1       1
-fdict                  /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/noisedict
-feat           1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams             /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/feat.params
-fillprob       1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate          100     100
-fsg                    
-fsgusealtpron      yes     yes
-fsgusefiller       yes     yes
-fwdflat        yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam        1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid       4       4
-fwdflatlw      8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin       25      25
-fwdflatwbeam       7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree        yes     yes
-hmm                    /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new
-input_endian       little      little
-jsgf                   
-keyphrase              
-kws                    /SpeechParsing/KeyPhrase.txt
-kws_delay      10      10
-kws_plp        1e-1        1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold      1       1.000000e+00
-latsize        5000        5000
-lda                    
-ldadim         0       0
-lifter         0       22
-lm                 
-lmctl                  
-lmname                 
-logbase        1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn                  
-logspec        no      no
-lowerf         133.33334   1.300000e+02
-lpbeam         1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam     7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw         6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf       30000       30000
-maxwpf         -1      -1
-mdef                   /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/mdef
-mean                   /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/means
-mfclogdir              
-min_endfr      0       0
-mixw                   /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/mixture_weights
-mixwfloor      0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr                   
-mmap           yes     yes
-ncep           13      13
-nfft           512     512
-nfilt          40      25
-nwpen          1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam          1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip            1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam        1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam       1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pip         1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_weight      3.0     3.000000e+00
-pl_window      5       5
-rawlogdir              
-remove_dc      no      no
-remove_noise       yes     yes
-remove_silence     yes     yes
-round_filters      yes     yes
-samprate       16000       1.600000e+04
-seed           -1      -1
-sendump                /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/sendump
-senlogdir              
-senmgau                
-silprob        0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec     no      no
-svspec                 0-12/13-25/26-38
-tmat                   /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/transition_matrices
-tmatfloor      0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn           4       4
-topn_beam      0       0
-toprule                
-transform      legacy      dct
-unit_area      yes     yes
-upperf         6855.4976   6.800000e+03
-uw         1.0     1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech     50      50
-vad_prespeech      20      20
-vad_startspeech    10      10
-vad_threshold      2.0     2.000000e+00
-var                    /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/variances
-varfloor       0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm        no      no
-verbose        no      no
-warp_params                
-warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam          7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip            0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen           0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(164): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 142108 * 8 bytes (1110 KiB) for CD tree
INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(117): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 222 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(476): Loading senones from dump file /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/sendump
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(500): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(563): Rows: 128, Columns: 5126
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(595): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(835): Maximum top-N: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 4101 * 32 bytes (128 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 5 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 42^3 * 2 bytes (144 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: kws_search.c(423): KWS(beam: -1080, plp: -23, default threshold 0, delay 10)
ERROR: "kws_search.c", line 174: The word '<word>' is missing in the dictionary
(^ I removed the actual word from the error message. There are some more lines like this and then it ends)
```

Terminal -

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm  /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new -infile  /SpeechParsing/Record_0039.wav -kws  /SpeechParsing/KeyPhrase.txt -time yes >  /tmp/Rtmpxuznpx/file3ef93d02074d
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]          [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc            none        none
-agcthresh      2.0     2.000000e+00
-allphone               
-allphone_ci        no      no
-alpha          0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale         20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw         1       1
-backtrace      no      no
-beam           1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath       yes     yes
-bestpathlw     9.5     9.500000e+00
-ceplen         13      13
-cmn            current     current
-cmninit        8.0     40,3,-1
-compallsen     no      no
-debug                  0
-dict                   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
-dictcase       no      no
-dither         no      no
-doublebw       no      no
-ds         1       1
-fdict                  
-feat           1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams             
-fillprob       1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate          100     100
-fsg                    
-fsgusealtpron      yes     yes
-fsgusefiller       yes     yes
-fwdflat        yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam        1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid       4       4
-fwdflatlw      8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin       25      25
-fwdflatwbeam       7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree        yes     yes
-hmm                    /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new
-input_endian       little      little
-jsgf                   
-keyphrase              
-kws                    /SpeechParsing/KeyPhrase.txt
-kws_delay      10      10
-kws_plp        1e-1        1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold      1       1.000000e+00
-latsize        5000        5000
-lda                    
-ldadim         0       0
-lifter         0       22
-lm                 
-lmctl                  
-lmname                 
-logbase        1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn                  
-logspec        no      no
-lowerf         133.33334   1.300000e+02
-lpbeam         1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam     7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw         6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf       30000       30000
-maxwpf         -1      -1
-mdef                   
-mean                   
-mfclogdir              
-min_endfr      0       0
-mixw                   
-mixwfloor      0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr                   
-mmap           yes     yes
-ncep           13      13
-nfft           512     512
-nfilt          40      25
-nwpen          1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam          1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip            1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam        1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam       1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pip         1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_weight      3.0     3.000000e+00
-pl_window      5       5
-rawlogdir              
-remove_dc      no      no
-remove_noise       yes     yes
-remove_silence     yes     yes
-round_filters      yes     yes
-samprate       16000       1.600000e+04
-seed           -1      -1
-sendump                
-senlogdir              
-senmgau                
-silprob        0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec     no      no
-svspec                 0-12/13-25/26-38
-tmat                   
-tmatfloor      0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn           4       4
-topn_beam      0       0
-toprule                
-transform      legacy      dct
-unit_area      yes     yes
-upperf         6855.4976   6.800000e+03
-uw         1.0     1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech     50      50
-vad_prespeech      20      20
-vad_startspeech    10      10
-vad_threshold      2.0     2.000000e+00
-var                    
-varfloor       0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm        no      no
-verbose        no      no
-warp_params                
-warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam          7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip            0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen           0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(164): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 142108 * 8 bytes (1110 KiB) for CD tree
INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(117): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 222 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(476): Loading senones from dump file /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/sendump
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(500): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(563): Rows: 128, Columns: 5126
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(595): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(835): Maximum top-N: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 138623 * 32 bytes (4331 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 1014 KiB for strings, 1677 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 134522 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 5 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 42^3 * 2 bytes (144 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: kws_search.c(420): KWS(beam: -1080, plp: -23, default threshold 0, delay 10)
INFO: continuous.c(307): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Apr  5 2016, AT: 10:42:56

(Then the output starts.)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing ANY R in this?

Comment: @42 - `system('pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm  /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new -infile  /SpeechParsing/Record_0039.wav -kws  /SpeechParsing/KeyPhrase.txt -time yes >  /tmp/Rtmpxuznpx/file3ef93d02074d')` vs running that command from the terminal itself.

Comment: Sure, you can run anything from a `system` call. That doesn't make it an R question.

Comment: The way it is being passed seems different from when I run it directly from the terminal. I don't know if the difference is to be attributed to the `system` command or `pocketsphinx_continuous`. I did come across some threads which mentioned that `system` has some idiosyncrasies so I'm not sure.

Comment: The environment variables may be different than when called from a bash shell.

Comment: Is that all? I don't think should affect the default values that the other arguments take.

Answer (score 0):

From the log in first case:

```
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(145): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/feat.params
```

and second case

```
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /SpeechParsing/Adaptations/en-in-new/feat.params
```

See 145 and 152 (line number)

It is clear that you are running different pocketsphinx installations. Maybe in first case it's pocketsphinx from `/usr/bin` which fails and in the second case it is more recent pocketsphinx in `/usr/local/bin` which works. system call does not always respect PATH configuration.

It is recommended to delete old version.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have connectivity. I ran both of them again explicitly pointing to `/usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous` but I still get the 145 and 152 difference and it still runs from the terminal but not from R. I couldn't find another pocketsphinx installation on my computer.

Comment: I removed the pocketsphinx_continuous file from `/usr/local/bin` and now neither of the calls work. I'm pretty sure both calls are pointing to the same installation. Is there some other parameter that I can look at?

Comment: You can search for multiple libraries called libpocketsphinx.so.something

Comment: Found three - /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so,
/usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so.3,
/usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so.3.0.0. First two are link to the third.

Comment: I also just uninstalled and reinstalled pocketsphinx but still no change.

Comment: This is what the two environment variables look like btw: `Sys.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
[1] "/usr/lib/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib"` and `> Sys.getenv('PKG_CONFIG_PATH')
[1] "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"`

Comment: Ok, you can set the dictionary in command line in system with `-dict /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict`, hopefully it will load it then.

Comment: Thanks! That got the command to start but now it returns a seg fault after about 20 lines of `INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update`.

Comment: And still says line 145 and not 152.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. Would that affect things by any chance?